# weighted average of neighbor elements in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x` and `w`. vector `w` is a numerical vector of weights the same length as x.
How can we get the  weighted average of neighbor elements in vector `x`( weighted average of the first element and second one , then weighted average of the secnod and third elements, ..... For example, these vectors are as follows:

```
x = c(0.0001560653, 0.0001591889, 0.0001599698, 0.0001607507, 0.0001623125,
      0.0001685597, 0.0002793819, 0.0006336307, 0.0092017241, 0.0092079042,
      0.0266525118, 0.0266889564, 0.0454923285, 0.0455676525, 0.0457005450)

w = c(2.886814e+03, 1.565955e+04, 9.255762e-02, 7.353589e+02, 1.568933e+03,
      5.108046e+05, 6.942338e+05, 4.912165e+04, 9.257674e+00, 3.609918e+02,
      8.090436e-01, 1.072975e+00, 1.359145e+00, 9.828314e+00, 9.455688e+01)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i) weighted.mean(x[i:(i+1)], w[i:(i+1)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional programming approach - will be slower than `@David Robinsons

```
# lots of `Map` \ functional programming
mapply(weighted.mean,
 x = Map(c, head(x,-1),tail(x,-1)), 
 w = Map(c, head(w,-1) ,tail(w,-1))
```